# How to inject CSS inside an iframe in a WebView? UWP

Tags: javascript, c#, css, webview, uwp-xaml

I wonder if it's possible to do something similar in UWP to what [Stylish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish) do for browsers because I have wrote a CSS for the web page I'm using inside my `WebView` but this web page have an iframe so I needed to apply the CSS to all the URLs starting with `"https://webchat.botframework.com/"` to make it works (on Stylish)

```
<WebView x:Name="WebView1" Source="https://www.blabla.net/bla/webchat.html" Width="490" Height="490" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Web page code

```
<body>
    <iframe lang="fr-FR" id="chat" style="width: 60vw; height: 95vh; margin-left: 20vw" src=''></iframe>

    <script>
        document.getElementById("chat").src =
            "https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/BitWcVaClient2?userid=" + create_UUID() +
            "&username=WW&v=4.2&l=fr-FR&s=ceraZE8go0A.lpa7tzuJ1H_rOJdJKWXibqg_aBrVQrHhhd432kU2e-M";

        function create_UUID() {
            var dt = new Date().getTime();
            var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
                var r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
                dt = Math.floor(dt / 16);
                return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
            });
            return uuid;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a js script and use js to do css injection.Then run the script using the eval function via InvokeScriptAsync.But the injection is to add new things to the original web page, so every time the web page is loaded, the process of injecting is repeated which means the **InvokeScriptAsync** will be triggered every time.You can write the following code in **DOMContentLoaded** of WebView.

```
string styleContent = "here is style content";
string injectContent = $"var st= document.createElement('style');document.body.appendChild(st);st.innerHTML = `{styleContent}`;";
await TestWeb.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { injectContent });
```

**Update:**

If you want to inject CSS inside an iframe,you can use the following js code to inject.The 'chat' is the name of iframe,you need to add a name to iframe.

```
private async void WebView_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    string cssContent = "body{background:black;}";
    string eval = "var frame = window.frames['chat'];" +
                  "var style = frame.document.createElement('style');" +
                  "frame.document.body.appendChild(style);" +
                  $"style.innerHTML = {cssContent}; ";
    await sender.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { cssContent });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but are you sure of your script?

Comment: I am showing the way to interact with the web page through WebView. This is an idea. The specific code needs to be adapted according to your actual situation.Don't forget to replace styleContent when you use it.Did you encounter issue while using it?

Comment: Yes..
`string styleContent = "body{ background-color: #111 !important; }";`
System.Exception: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101'

Comment: It didn't report an exception when I used your styleContent in VS2017.Can you provide a simple sample that could reproduce the issue?

Comment: It was my fault I was calling my `method` before the `WebView`, it's working now I just need to find a way to enable the CSS for the botframework URLs

Comment: If it solved your issue,you can mark it and that would be helpful for other communities who meet the same problem.

Comment: The real problem is with the iframe inside the web page, so basicaly my problem isn't solved

Comment: The web page isn't mine and I don't understand what is the purpose of the `string eval` I don't think it's used anywhere

Comment: Eval is the run command that comes with js, which treats the incoming string as a js script and runs. So when injecting js, you can use the eval function whether it's your own web page or someone else's web page.

Comment: Can you provide a simple sample that could reproduce the issue? In this case, it's convenient for finding and solving issues.

Comment: [My code + screenshots](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JakI7PeYNRd87vUuXY9k54COtjkFIRPS/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: First of all, you used iframe, and it is a different source of the website, which leads to limited js injection. In other words, inject js into the iframe, only the same site can do this. You could access the URL of this iframe in the WebView,without nesting iframe. Second, there is a problem with the css code you injected. You want to modify the image directly by the content of the .ac-image class. This is not possible. You can test whether this code can be run in the browser. If you has js issue, you can find js related people to solve. We can provide you with only the js injection method.